# Fast, Cheap, Dedicated Hosting

Tags: server, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I'm looking for dedicated hosting with at least 1GB of RAM that doesn't hurt the wallet too much. Specifically it should have goods speed around the world as well.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Do you need "true dedicated" or can you get by with a virtual-dedicated?

If a VPS will work I highly recommend linode.com, slicehost or vps.net.

If you need true dedicated i would recommend theplanet.com, hostgator.com or servint.net

Answer (score 3):

Can't speak for Arvixe's quality, but for $10 more than their VPS plan, you can get a 1GB VPS plan from DreamHost, an established hosting company with a good track record, also with unlimited storage and bandwidth.

Media Temple is another popular web host, and their 1GB VPS plan is also $50/month (or $41/month if you pay yearly). However, they limit storage to 40GB and bandwidth to 650GB.

You might also want to look into Amazon EC2. With EC2, Media Temple and DreamHost, you can also scale your hosting plan as needed. That could save you money as well as ensure your app has room to grow (and won't die when there's a sudden traffic spike).

If you want a true dedicated server (very few reasons for it these days), then it's going to cost you a lot more ($105+/month for 1GB at Arvixe, $89/month for 4GB at DreamHost). However, DreamHost is currently running a special for $69/month if you sign up for a full year's hosting. I think that's just for the first year though.

Comment: I second staying away from an unknown company (or at least one that's reliability is not verifiable).  I've been on Media Temple's VPS server for the past six months or so and I have no plans of leaving anytime soon.

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote a blog post about ["VPS/VM vs Dedicated vs Cloud Servers: Hosting options and cost comparisons"](http://codeblog.theg2.net/2010/10/vpsvm-vs-dedicated-vs-cloud-servers.html), and have to agree with others that say you should look into VM or VPS hosting options before jumping into a dedicated server. There are lots of hosting providers that offer virtual machines for a lot cheaper than what you can get a dedicated server for.

I'd recommend that you look at [Superb.net](http://Superb.net) and compare their [Virtual Private Server](http://www.superb.net/vps/compare-hosting-plans.php) (VPS) and [Dedicated servers](http://www.superb.net/dedicated-servers/base-server-plans/). Dedicated usually starts around $70-$80 a month, where as VPS usually starts around $20 a month. They also have some nice high end virtual servers for reasonable prices, such as 4GB RAM, 8 cores, 320GB Hard Drive, and 4000GB bandwidth for $150 a month. They have an introductory special going on right now for 25% that knocks it down to $112.50, which is much cheaper than a comparable dedicated server.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [Arvixe](http://www.arvixe.com/). They're really inexpensive, good service, and unlimited disk space. I can't speak to how much RAM they maintain, but they're pretty top notch.

Answer (score 0):

This is a list of many of the .NET hosters out there that Microsoft supports, http://www.microsoft.com/web/hosting/home.  You can check out price ranges, reviews, etc.

Another great host if you are into the LAMP stack is Slice Host, http://www.slicehost.com/.  They are great for scalability as your site grows and for a multi-purpose host that you have more control over.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as no one suggested this yet, I've used [GoDaddy](http://www.godaddy.com/hosting/dedicated-servers.aspx?ci=9014) for 3 years now and have had 3 dedicated servers with them. Server's are not that expensive and are actually quite reliable. They've also recently expanded their OS options as well so you actually have like 6 times the configuration options now than when I started with my first server.

I'm currently paying $220/m for their "64-bit Windows Memory Hog" server and it's pretty powerful. Of course, it all depends on your needs.

Oh, and if you know what you want and call them to order it, they might give you a discount on your first month, or year if you pre-pay.